# Permission trouble when including pre-populated sqlite database with app on Android Marshmallow

Tags: android, sqlite, android-permissions

I'm trying to include a prepopulated sqlite database with my app. I have put it at `main/assets/dbname.db` and copying it in `onCreate()` of my custom `Application` subclass.

It works great for lower versions of Android. But on Marshmallow, I'm hitting a barrier with permissions. I cannot ask for storage writing permission unless I'm inside an activity. So I moved the db copying part inside the first activity that launches, inside `onCreate()` of the activity. But then for some reason, right after I grant the permission, my app closes. I have to start it again for it to work.

I've been looking for best practices on how to provide a prepopulated database for Android Marshmallow and I haven't had much success. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this plugin [Android SQLite Asset Helper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) which seems to have worked without any issues.